# How to start RabbitMQ that installed by source after CentOS 7 boot?

Tags: rabbitmq

My English is not good.
I can run RabiitMQ mannually.
I want run RabiitMQ archives on system boot.
I've configured /etc/rc.local, but It doesn't work.I don't know why.Those that in /etc/rc.local works, but RabbitMQ doesn't work.
The following are what I configured.
`/opt/dev/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_server-3.6.6/rabbitmq-server`
what should I do?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
chkconfig rabbitmq-server on
```

> The server is not started as a daemon by default when the RabbitMQ server package is installed. To start the daemon by default when the system boots, as an administrator run chkconfig rabbitmq-server on.

Source: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html

Comment: sorry, but I installed rabbitMQ by source, I didn't use rpm.Does it work?